# Is there a DMV that shows the aggregate logical reads on a SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, dmv

I want to use this metric to compare 2 servers. I've looked at sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats, but this is missing logical. Also looked at query_stats, but that only includes cached plans.

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you might be after you may find in a different DMV:

```
select * from sys.dm_os_performance_counters
```

[image]

[sys.dm_os_performance_counters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187743.aspx)

But pay attention to these `features`:

> Counters like Page reads/sec appear to be cumulative. Which just
>   blows my poor head. In that case it should be named like 'pages read'.
>   So to get actual Page reads/sec you have to do smth like:
>
> divide the counter value by amount of seconds since startup (you can
>   get it by select datediff(ss,create_date, getdate()) as uptime from
>   sys.databases where name = 'tempdb').